# nls when the data is a convoluted spectra (variable number of variables)

Tags: r, spectrum, nls

I have some spectrum data that looks like one of the multiplets when is plotted:
http://journals.prous.com/journals/dof/19982303/html/df230301/images/keiferf3.gif

How it is seen in the image, all the peaks are realy close among each other, so I would like to do some deconvolution using nls function, like it was posted before ([R: Fitting Gaussian peaks to density plot data using nls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230801/r-fitting-gaussian-peaks-to-density-plot-data-using-nls)), but using a Lorentzian function instead:

```
y <- 1/(pi*a*(1+((x-x0)/a)^2))
```

In my case, x0 is the peak maximum (and length(x0) is the number of peaks), so I only need to optimize 'a'.

However, my problem is not related to perform that, but in writing a robust script that would deconvolute any spectrum, taking the number of peaks as input information.

My first idea was to write the lorentzian function and leave the 'a' as a vector (to apply thereafter a sum of all lorentzian curves), but R doesn't recognize this structure:

```
for (i in 1:length(x0)) {
    f[i]<-function(a) { y <- 1/(pi*a[i]*(1+((x-x0[i])/a[i])^2)) }
}

fit <- nls(sum(f[1:length(x0)]), start=list(a=rep(1, times=length(x0))))
```

**Update:**

This is my sample, in .csv format (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66EHLI5AufhbjlWcW9rYXl1UFk/edit?usp=sharing). Data is filled in 2 rows. The first one has the frequency (in ppm), and the second the intensity. For this data, I will pick 5 peaks, so I would do 'nls' on formula=f[1]+f[2]+f[3]+f[4]+f[5] and I would have 5 parametres (a[1:5]) to evaluate.

Comment: Side note: `f <- 1/pi*a*(1+(x-x0)/a^2)` is a vectorized replacement for your loop.

Comment: I know that my code is not well written, but I thought posting the code will somehow help to understand my request.

Comment: Of course, no worries :) This is just an R-specific hint.

Comment: Peeking at the referenced question: clearly this only works when the peaks are well-separated (e.g. Rayleigh criterion).  Given that, I think you need to "explain" to `nls` that you've got a set of variables to fit. Maybe make `list` whose elements are the various `f[i]` ?

Comment: Can you provide sample data, say the data from the spectrum in your link?

Comment: @tonytonov your vectorized version will produce a value, but I think the OP wants a collection of defined functions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I left the logic as it is stated in the question; this is not even a partial answer, of course.

Comment: Why do you want to fit and deconvolve the spectra? Particulary, do you want to deconvolve so you can then get a better fit, or do you want to fit and use the band position as the ultimately deconvolved version of the spectrum? Also, what kind of spectra are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about NMR spectra. I'm currently working with biological samples that have lots of metabolits, so I have lots overlapping peaks in my spectra. Usually, people only compare this kind of spectra performing PCA analysis, but I would like to go further and to do that I need to extract the area of each pick alone.

Comment: OK, but do you need the area under a peak, or just its location?

Comment: I need the area, but I can calculate it easily if I have the function with 'a'.

Comment: With this function (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima) I found all the local maxima and then I choose the 5 with highest intensities. These 5 values would be x0[1:5] in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the 'as.formula' command, which allows to convert any character string to formula. Therefore, I manage to create a for loop that creates the sum of lorentzian curves. In my example, parameters a[1:5] are now defined as a-e, but with sprintf I can use the vector nomenclature as well.

```
cac<-"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for (i in 1:length(x0)) {
    letter<-substr(cac, i,i)
    formulae[i]<-sprintf("1/(pi*%s*(1+((spectra[1,]-%f)/%s)^2))", letter,x0[i],letter)
    coeff[i]<-sprintf("%s=1", letter)
}
formula2<-paste(formulae, collapse="+")
formulo<-paste("spectra[2,] ~", formula2, sep="")
coeffs<-paste(coeff, collapse=",")

fit<-as.formula(paste("nls(",formulo,",start=list(",coeffs,"))", sep=""))
```

So, all this code brings me the following formula for the posted example:

```
"nls(spectra[2,] ~1/(pi*a*(1+((spectra[1,]-2.156460)/a)^2))+1/(pi*b*(1+((spectra[1,]-2.170150)/b)^2))+1/(pi*c*(1+((spectra[1,]-2.184820)/c)^2))+1/(pi*d*(1+((spectra[1,]-2.163550)/d)^2))+1/(pi*e*(1+((spectra[1,]-2.142040)/e)^2)), start=list(a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1))
```

However, it seems that the formula does not work, but this wasn't the aim of this thread, so I can say now it's closed (I opened a new one to try to solve it).